# JSF page ends in a redirect loop

Tags: java, jsf, loops, redirect

My browser is always returning a redirect loop and I have no idea why, it looks like when I access **login.html** it is calling some of my methods.

Here is the login.html file:

```
<ui:composition
    template="/templates/master.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <ui:define name="body">

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <h:form class="form-horizontal">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Bem vindo a Sergio's</legend>
                            <br/>
                            <p>Preencha os campos abaixo para entrar no sistema.</p>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="user">Usuário</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <h:inputText required="true" id="user" value="#{loginController.username}" class="input-medium" />
                                    <h:message for="user" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="password">Senha</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <h:inputSecret required="true" id="password" value="#{loginController.password}" class="input-medium"/>
                                    <h:message for="password" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-actions">
                                <h:commandButton action="#{loginController.login()}" class="btn btn-primary" value="Entrar"/>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </h:form>
                    <h:messages/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

And here is the LoginController:

```
package com.erp3.gui.controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
public class LoginController {

    public Boolean isLoggedIn = false;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private FacesMessage facesMessage;
    public ExternalContext externalContent;

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Boolean getIsLoggedIn() {
        return isLoggedIn;
    }

    public void setIsLoggedIn(Boolean isLoggedIn) {
        this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
    }

    public void login() throws IOException {
        if (this.getUsername().equals("daniel") && this.getPassword().equals("123")) {
            this.isLoggedIn = true;
            externalContent = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
            externalContent.getSessionMap().put("loginController", this);
            externalContent.redirect(externalContent.getRequestContextPath() + "/views/home.html");
        } else {
            this.isLoggedIn = false;
            facesMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Usuário ou senha inválida.", username);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
            externalContent.redirect(externalContent.getRequestContextPath() + "/views/login.htm");
        }
    }

    public void logOut() throws IOException {
        externalContent = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        externalContent.getSessionMap().remove("loginController");
        externalContent.redirect(externalContent.getRequestContextPath() + "/views/login.html");
    }

}
```

I have a master.html that is my template and it is calling a top.html with this content:

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="icon-user"></i>
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Conta</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#{loginController.logout}">Sair</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: I assume you're using the credentials _daniel:123_?

Comment: the login page is not even been loaded and it is correctly defined on web.xml

Comment: QUESTION EDITED, FORGOT ABOUT ANOTHER DETAIL, A PAGE CALLING LOGINCONTROLLER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EL expressions in *template text* are immediately evaluated during render response and treated as value expressions. I.e. their return value is been printed as part of HTML output. "Plain vanilla" HTML is *also* template text. So the following

```html
<li><a href="#{loginController.logOut()}">Sair</a></li>
```

will basically invoke the method, print its returned value as `href` URL during render response. The resulting HTML is then:

```html
<li><a href="">Sair</a></li>
```

*(yes, the `href` is empty because you actually returned `void` instead of a valid `String)`*

But inside that method you're telling JSF to redirect to the login page and hence it ends up in an infinite loop.

This is not what you actually want. You intend to invoke it as a backing bean action method. You should be using fullworthy JSF `UICommand` component for this, such as `<h:commandLink>`.

```html
<li><h:form><h:commandLink value="Sair" action="#{loginController.logOut()}" /></h:form></li>
```

This way you can also change your `logOut()` method to return a fullworthy navigation outcome:

```
public String logOut() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
    return "/views/login.html?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

The `ExternalContext#redirect()` is supposed to be used only when you want to redirect to a non-JSF URL, or when you're actually not inside an action method.

Comment: I'm typing another question so if possible, keep an eye on it, please

Comment: Note that I've updated the answer how to properly invoke an action which invalidates the session and returns a navigation outcome which should be redirected.

Answer (score 1):

found the problem, on my `top.html`, I'm calling `loginController.logOut()` on a link and I don't know why it is auto executing, is not waiting for my click so I changed the `<a>` for `<h:commandLink/>`